Use a macOS specific SwiftUI view in a Mac Catalyst app
I have a Catalyst app using UIKit that runs on iOS and macOS. In one screen I want to use the LocalAuthenticationView that is only available on macOS.
I cannot directly use it in the app because I cannot use #if os(macos). I tried creating a macOS plugin bundle but I do not really know how to expose it.
In the macOS plugin bundle I can create a class with a method that creates the view, but I cannot expose it as SwiftUI view just as Any because it needs to be an Objc compatible type.
@objc(AuthenticationViewProvider)
protocol AuthenticationViewProvider: NSObjectProtocol {
    init()

    func createView() -> Any
}

Then in the Mac Catalyst app I can load the class, call the method but the return type can be only cast to any View
let pluginClass = bundle.classNamed(className) as? AuthenticationViewProvider.Type
let provider: AuthenticationViewProvider = pluginClass.init()
if let view = provider.createView() as? any View {
   let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: view) // ERROR: Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
}

So I do not know how to use the loaded view in the app.
Alternatively I can maybe use LAAuthenticationView which is a NSView but I do not think there is any way to load a NSView from the macOS plugin bundle and display it in a UIKit Mac Catalyst app.

Think of MacCatalyst as a totally separate platform. If something is not available there, it's not available, in the same way that NSViews are not available on iOS.

Well I already do some AppKit calls from Catalyst to NSWindow etc via a macOS plugin bundle .. so it got me thinking maybe I can even do this.

SwiftUI does not work with existentials any View there are workarounds but they are highly discouraged. You should watch Demystify SwiftUI
